# Must a field extension contain an element of particular degree?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose $F$ is a field, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $F$, $[F(\alpha,\beta):F] = mn$ for positive integers $m$ and $n$, and $[F(\alpha):F] = m$. Must there exist a $\gamma \in F(\alpha,\beta)$ for which $\gamma \notin F(\alpha)$, $[F(\gamma):F] = n$, and $F(\alpha,\gamma) = F(\alpha,\beta)$?

This came up when looking for the Galois group of the splitting field of $x^4 - 14x^2 +9$ over the rationals Q. The roots are $\pm \sqrt{7 \pm 2 \sqrt{10}}$, and I have convinced myself that the splitting field is $K = Q(\sqrt{7 + 2 \sqrt{10}},\sqrt{7 - 2 \sqrt{10}})$, an extension of $Q$ of degree 8. I was looking for a more convenient set of generators for describing the automorphisms of $K$, but was having trouble finding what I wanted, which led to the above question. That is, I was looking for a $\gamma \in Q(\sqrt{7 + 2 \sqrt{10}},\sqrt{7 - 2 \sqrt{10}})$ such that both $\gamma \notin Q(\sqrt{7 + 2 \sqrt{10}})$ and $[Q(\gamma):Q] =2$. I thought this would be useful so I could describe the 8 automorphisms of $K$ as the maps $\sqrt{7 + 2 \sqrt{10}} \mapsto \pm \sqrt{7 \pm 2 \sqrt{10}}$ and $\gamma \mapsto \pm \gamma$.

Comment: While your question is interesting, the original problem you were dealing with is much simpler than that.  Is the polynomial in question $x^4-14x^2+9$ (you wrote $x^4-14x+9$, which does not have $\pm\sqrt{7\pm2\sqrt{10}}$ as roots)?  If that is the case, the roots can be written as $\pm\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{5}$, and it can be easily seen that the splitting field of $x^4-14x^2+9$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $K:=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2,\sqrt5]$.  Thus, the Galois group of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$.  (Don't delete the question, though.)

Comment: Yes I did mean $x^4 - 14x^2 + 9$, thanks. I am thinking over your comments.

Comment: @Batominovski So I goofed a computation convincing me $\sqrt{7 - 2 \sqrt{10}} \notin Q(\sqrt{7 + 2 \sqrt{10}})$, which led to me thinking that $K= Q(\sqrt{7 + 2 \sqrt{10}},\sqrt{7 - 2 \sqrt{10}})$ was of degree 8 over $Q$. Now that you mention it, it is easy to see that $K = Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 5)$, but I am having trouble understanding how I might have discovered that without your insight.
I've tried playing around with elements in $Q(\sqrt{7 + 2 \sqrt{10}})$, to see if I can make any of $\pm \sqrt 2 \pm \sqrt 5$ appear, but
the best I can do is make $\sqrt{10}$ appear.

Comment: Should I just notice that $7 + 2\sqrt{10} = 2 + 2\sqrt{10} + 5 = (\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 5)^2$ ?  

I've also notice that if you have a polynomial over $Q$ of the form $x^4 -2(a+b)x^2 + (a-b)^2$, for non-perfect squares $a,b$, then the roots are $\pm \sqrt a \pm \sqrt b$, but only noticed that after your comment.

Comment: You might try to factorize $x^4-14x^2+9$ like this:  $$x^4-14x^2+9=(x^2-3)^2-8x^2=(x^2-3)^2-(2\sqrt2\,x)^2\,.$$  This means $$x^4-14x^2+9=\big(x^2-2\sqrt2\,x-3\big)\,\big(x^2+2\sqrt2\,x-3\big)\,.$$  We have $$x^2-2\sqrt2\,x-3=(x-\sqrt2)^2-5=(x-\sqrt 2)-(\sqrt5)^2=(x-\sqrt2-\sqrt 5)(x-\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5)\,.$$
Similarly, $$x^2+2\sqrt2\,x-3=(x+\sqrt2)^2-5=(x+\sqrt 2)-(\sqrt5)^2=(x+\sqrt2-\sqrt 5)(x+\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5)\,.$$

Comment: Clever, thanks. Perhaps my takeaway is to look for better factoring techniques before going straight to ``quadratic in $x^2$''.

Comment: In general, if you have polynomials of the form $x^4+px^2+q$, maybe, you can try first to factorize like what I did above.  I do not guarantee that it will be better than using the method $$x^4+px^2+q=\left(x^2+\frac{p}{2}\,x\right)^2-\frac{p^2-4q}{4}\,,$$ which I assume you used to get $\pm\sqrt{7\pm2\sqrt{10}}$.  But it provides an alternative way to see what the roots can be rewritten as.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many counterexamples.

Perhaps the simplest: take $f(x)$ to be an irreducible polynomial with Galois group $S_m$ for $m > 4$, and let $n = m-1$. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two roots of $f(x)$. Then $F = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ has degree $m(m-1) = mn$, and $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ has degree $m$. But the splitting field of $f(x)$ doesn't even contain a subfield of degree $n=m-1$, since that would give an index $m-1$ subgroup of $S_m$ which does not exist for $m > 4$.

Another counterexample: take $n=m=2$, and $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$ and $\beta = \sqrt[4]{2}$.

More generally, if $F$ is any field of degree $mn$ with a subfield of degree $m$, then, by the primitive element theorem, you can write $E = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ and $F = \mathbf{Q}(\beta) = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$, so your claim would imply that any field of degree $mn$ with a subfield of degree $m$ is the compositum of two fields of degree $m$ and $n$. Using Galois theory, you can then translate this into a property of subgroups of the Galois group of the splitting field $G$ (which I won't write down here) which need not hold for general $G$.

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking over your response.

Comment: Hmm, the only example I understand at the moment is $\alpha = \sqrt 2$ and $\beta = \sqrt[4]{2}$, so I will come back to this after some more study.